# Spotify Implicit Grant Flow with React - user login

Tags: reactjs, spotify

This React Component below connects an app to Spotify using the [Implicit Grant Flow](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#implicit-grant-flow), redirecting the app back to my client after token is obtained for user.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Credentials from './spotify-auth.js'
import './Spotify.css'


class SpotifyAuth extends Component {  
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isAuthenticatedWithSpotify: false,
      menu: this.props.userId.menu
    };
    this.state.handleRedirect = this.handleRedirect.bind(this);
  };


  generateRandomString(length) {
    let text = '';
    const possible =
      'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    }
    return text;
    } 

  getHashParams() {
    const hashParams = {};
    const r = /([^&;=]+)=?([^&;]*)/g;
    const q = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    let e = r.exec(q);
    while (e) {
      hashParams[e[1]] = decodeURIComponent(e[2]);
      e = r.exec(q);
    }
    return hashParams;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    //if (this.props.isAuthenticated) {
    const params = this.getHashParams();

    const access_token = params.access_token;
    const state = params.state;
    const storedState = localStorage.getItem(Credentials.stateKey);
    localStorage.setItem('spotifyAuthToken', access_token);
    localStorage.getItem('spotifyAuthToken');

    if (window.localStorage.getItem('authToken')) {
      this.setState({ isAuthenticatedWithSpotify: true });
    };
    if (access_token && (state == null || state !== storedState)) {
      alert('Click "ok" to finish authentication with Spotify');
    } else {
      localStorage.removeItem(Credentials.stateKey);
    }
    // DO STUFF WITH ACCEES TOKEN HERE
    this.props.onConnectWithSpotify(access_token); 
  };

  handleRedirect(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.props.createMessage('You linked your Spotify account!', 'success');

    const params = this.getHashParams();
    const access_token = params.access_token;
    console.log(access_token);

    const state = this.generateRandomString(16);
    localStorage.setItem(Credentials.stateKey, state);

    let url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize';
    url += '?response_type=token';
    url += '&client_id=' + encodeURIComponent(Credentials.client_id);
    url += '&scope=' + encodeURIComponent(Credentials.scope);
    url += '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent(Credentials.redirect_uri);
    url += '&state=' + encodeURIComponent(state);
    window.location = url; 
  };

  render() {
      return (
        <div className="button_container">
            <h1 className="title is-4"><font color="#C86428">Welcome</font></h1>
            <div className="Line" /><br/>
              <button className="sp_button" onClick={(event) => this.handleRedirect(event)}>
                <strong>LINK YOUR SPOTIFY ACCOUNT</strong>
              </button>
        </div>
      )
  }
}
export default SpotifyAuth;
```

However, before redirect I would like to depict the following page, or a pop up, with defined scopes and 'agree' button:

---

[image]

---

According to Spotify docs for [Implicit Flow](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/), redirecting the user to `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=5fe01282e94241328a84e7c5cc169164&redirect_uri=http:%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fcallback&scope=user-read-private%20user-read-email&response_type=token&state=123`

> ...performs a couple of actions:
>
> The user is asked to authorize access within the scopes. The Spotify Accounts >service presents details of the scopes for which access is being sought.
>   If the user is not logged in, they are prompted to do so using their Spotify >username and password.
>   When the user is logged in, they are asked to authorize access to the data sets >defined in the scopes.

None of the actions above happen with my code above when I call `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?`, I just get the token.

What is wrong?

---

I have found this codepen example, where a user is prompted a log in page:

[Spotify Implicit Grant Auth Popup](https://codepen.io/leemartin/pen/EOxxYR?editors=1010)

How do I add this functionality to my component above?

Comment: Do you have the stylesheet for Spotify to be able to use their styling, and then create a component of the above functionality and then on click, you will call a function instead of handleRedirect, that call's the above component, and as they agree it will finish the flow calling handleRedirect, if that is what you want let me know

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I want. Where can I find the stylesheet ?

Comment: Typically the scopes grant page is the responsibility of the OAuth provider, not clients. Any reason why you would want to replicate it in your app?

Comment: Implicit Flow is for client auth, no? For no particular reason I just would like to have scopes as a pop up

Comment: Yes the flow doesn't require a server, but the login and consent is still part of the authentication provider, not the client. You'd be duplicating it. You'd also need to store consent on the client so you don't ask again. Also would need to implement access revoke. These all are auth provider responsibilities.

Comment: I am assuming the Spotify login ui is already displayed in a pop-up. Isn't the consent screen shown there right after user login?

Comment: No I have only a button which handles token retrieval and redirect after it. Token is being stored as props and passed along to my server. Bit I don’t have this intermediate step with agreement. That’s what’s missing

Comment: You don't need to. The authentication flow is responsibility of the auth provider.

Comment: not a matter of needing, it's a matter of wanting.

Comment: What scopes are you requesting? Are you making sure to revoke the access for the app before you go through the auth flow?

Comment: Implicit flow is a wrong way to go. You should ideally create a back channel and should use authorization code flow instead.

Comment: @CameronDowner scopes are `user-read-private user-read-email user-read-playback-state playlist-modify-public playlist-modify-private'`, and no I'm not revoking. what you see above is all there is to the flow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**NOTE:
Once you have accepted the scopes using one email id you wont be shown scope page again. Scopes are asked just once in the start. If you want to see scope page again then you have to authorize new email id.**

I have created a react app to feel how your code is working. I ran the following code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export const authEndpoint = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize';
class SpotifyAuth extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isAuthenticatedWithSpotify: false
      // menu: this.props.userId.menu
    };
    this.state.handleRedirect = this.handleRedirect.bind(this);
  }

  generateRandomString(length) {
    let text = '';
    const possible =
      'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    }
    return text;
  }

  getHashParams() {
    const hashParams = {};
    const r = /([^&;=]+)=?([^&;]*)/g;
    const q = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    let e = r.exec(q);
    while (e) {
      hashParams[e[1]] = decodeURIComponent(e[2]);
      e = r.exec(q);
    }
    return hashParams;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    //if (this.props.isAuthenticated) {
    const params = this.getHashParams();

    const access_token = params.access_token;
    const state = params.state;
    const storedState = localStorage.getItem('stateKey');
    localStorage.setItem('spotifyAuthToken', access_token);
    localStorage.getItem('spotifyAuthToken');

    if (window.localStorage.getItem('authToken')) {
      this.setState({ isAuthenticatedWithSpotify: true });
    }
    if (access_token && (state == null || state !== storedState)) {
      alert('Click "ok" to finish authentication with Spotify');
    } else {
      localStorage.removeItem('stateKey');
    }
    console.log(access_token);
    // DO STUFF WITH ACCEES TOKEN HERE
    // this.props.onConnectWithSpotify(access_token);
  }

  handleRedirect(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('You linked your Spotify account!', 'success');

    const params = this.getHashParams();
    const access_token = params.access_token;
    console.log(access_token);

    const state = this.generateRandomString(16);
    localStorage.setItem('stateKey', state);

    // let url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize';
    // url += '?response_type=token';
    // url +=
    //   '&client_id=' + encodeURIComponent('f09fbf600009433dadce5836c57584c3');
    // url += '&scope=' + encodeURIComponent('user-top-read');
    // url += '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent('http://localhost:3000/abc');
    // url += '&state=' + encodeURIComponent(state);
    // url += '&show_dialog=true';
    let url =
      'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize' +
      '?response_type=code' +
      '&client_id=f09fbf600009433dadce5836c57584c3' +
      '&scope=' +
      encodeURIComponent('user-read-private%20user-read-email') +
      '&redirect_uri=' +
      encodeURIComponent('http://localhost:3000/loginsuccess');
    window.location = url;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="button_container">
        <h1 className="title is-4">
          <font color="#C86428">Welcome</font>
        </h1>
        <div className="Line" />
        <br />
        <button
          className="sp_button"
          onClick={(event) => this.handleRedirect(event)}
        >
          <strong>LINK YOUR SPOTIFY ACCOUNT</strong>
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SpotifyAuth;
```

I believe that there is no problem with the code when I hardcoded the url instead of taking values from `Credential`. I was able to see the scope page
It will be better if you could verify that scopes saved in `Credential` are correct.

Also I have commented out `this.props.createMessage` method which is abstract for me and might cause some issue.

[image]

Comment: Just to add to that scopes are meant to give user consent.

Comment: You can also go into your account settings and revoke the access for your app. You should be shown the scopes again afterwards: https://www.spotify.com/uk/account/apps/

Comment: @CameronDowner this helped a lot as well, Cameron, thanks for the link.